# System cleanup (Lubuntu 16.04)

Tags: cleanup

I've just done an upgrade of my lubuntu. I see for example that I have in the system old linux kernels. How can I clean and tidy my OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you like the command line, you can try `sudo apt autoremove` to get rid of some of the old kernels.

If you prefer a GUI, you could try [Ubuntu Cleaner](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/free-space-ubuntu-cleaner-janitor-app), a fork of the crud-cleaning portion of the late lamented Ubuntu Tweak application.  From the linked article, you can install it from a ppa by issuing these commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gerardpuig/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-cleaner`

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` works, but only partially

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: That remove some old kernel but not all